Langchain Agents and tools: how to pass extra argument to tools other than input
My LLM app contains a session for each user and userid.
Here I want to pass userId (id of user who is currently using LLM app) to getPrice tools.
How to send userId to tools?
from langchain import hub
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_react_agent
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langchain_openai import OpenAI
import requests
from langchain.tools import Tool
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage

llm=ChatOpenAI()
prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/react-chat")

def getPrice(input,extra):
    print("input +++",input,extra)
    url="https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets/"+input.lower()
    response=requests.get(url)
    price=response.json()["data"]["priceUsd"]
    return price

apicall=Tool(
    name="getCryptoPrice",
    func=getPrice,
    description="use to get the price for any given crypto from user input"
)
tools=[apicall]

agent = create_react_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True
)

agent_executor.invoke(
    {
        # what is the price of cardano
        "input": "what is the price of cardano",
        # Notice that chat_history is a string, since this prompt is aimed at LLMs, not chat models
        "chat_history": "Human: Hi! My name is Bob\nAI: Hello Bob! Nice to meet you",

    }
)

I tried to pass userid in invoke, but it's not working as it's not valid syntax.

I had issues with passing information to tools. So what I did instead was build an intent classifier. Before calling the LLM or triggering any function, I first run the incoming text through the intent classifier.
The intent classifier then returns a function name. Since these are regular Python functions, I can pass any information to them.
Here's a code example:

from qdrant_client import QdrantClient

client = QdrantClient(url="http://localhost:6333")

docs = client.search(
    collection_name="intent_classifier",
    query_vector=the_vectorized_question,
    with_payload=["intent"],
    limit=1,
)

tools = {
"do_search": do_search
}

intent = doc[0].__dict__["intent"]
answer = tools[intent](user, raw_question)

def do_search(user, raw_question):
    # do some RAG stuff
    context_data = get_context_data_from_rag_stuff(raw_question)
    return llm.invoke({"question": raw_question, "context": context_data})

Instead of a similarity search, you could also make a query to the LLM to determine the intent.
NOTE: to keep things simple, I left out validation logic.
